# WOW.js and scrolling div

Tags: html, css, wow.js

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) using `wow.js`. I uses it in a div, not for the entire page. I scroll the div, not the page. And this Javascript doesn't work .

What do I need to fix?

```css
<style>
   body {
      background-color: #78ccf0;
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0;    
   }
   .header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 214px;
      background-color: #000000;
   }
   .div_body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 450px;
      background-color: #fff;
      overflow: scroll;
      background-image:url('page_fon.jpg');
      font-size: 14pt;
   }
   .footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 270px;
      background-color: #000000;
   }   
</style>
```

```html
<div class="div_body">text
  <div class="wow bounceInRight" >animated text</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you include wow.js in your html?

Comment: Yes, I created link for wow.js  like this:<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script>
              new WOW().init();
              </script>

Comment: And this I added. Tried in <head></head> and in the end before </body>

Comment: If I do not use overflow:scroll-y everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

To use animated.css you have to add the class "animated".